# How can display DialogFragment if I click on another point of View

Tags: android, view, dialogfragment

I have in a Android Application, a DialogFragment that is show, when I click on FloatingActionButton.

Now, this is the xml file of DialogFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelStartDate"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/start_date"/>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/startDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelStartDate"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:endYear="2100"
        android:startYear="1900"
        >
    </DatePicker>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelEndDate"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/labelStartDate"
        android:text="@string/end_date"/>

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/endDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelEndDate"
        android:layout_below="@id/labelStartDate"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:endYear="2100"
        android:startYear="1900"
        >
    </DatePicker>

   ......
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my Fragment, I open the DialogFragment in this mode:

```
FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertsDialogFragment dialog = AlertsDialogFragment.newInstance();
                dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"");
            }
        });
```

Now, whit this code, I'm able to display the Dialogfragment, but now I have two problems:

1) If I show, the Dialog, then I click on another point on the view, the Dialog is hide.
2) If I click on fourth (for example) editText, I can't click on the next EditText, and I must hide keyboard, then click on edittext...

> EDIT

For the second point, when I display the DialogFragment, I see this:
[image]

But if I click on the Reaction Text, I can't see the text Status as you can see from this image:
[image]

Comment: For 1st point to `dialog.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` to avoid dismiss Dialog on outside touch and your 2nd point is not clear

Comment: for point (1) do `dialog.setCancelableOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: Ok, if I use this code: dialog.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false), I fixed the first point

Comment: I have EDIT, my question

Answer (score 0):

1st point: use the method setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) on dialog object

```
public void onClick(View v) {                 
AlertsDialogFragment dialog = AlertsDialogFragment.newInstance(); 
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"");
```

}

other information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean))

2nd point: the query is not clear, anyway I try to deduce it: you want move to the next field(editText)

The solution is use a keyboard action in your editText, so you must add this attribute

```
android:imeOptions = actionNext
```

in your editText.

In this manner you still will not see the next focusable fields(editText), but  the system applies the "actionNext" action to the current EditText when the user  select Next(**carriage return key**) to move to the next field

you can find other informations about keyboard actions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#Actions)